# Is there any workaround to enable Minor versions on custom lists?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
list.EnableMinorVersions = true;
```

but the following error appear:

> The list does not support minor versioning

my List type is custom list and I know we can't enable Minor versions on SharePoint lists, the **minor versions works only for lists based on SPDocumentLibrary**.

but is there any workaround to enable Minor versions on custom lists?

Comment: can i ask, why you need to enable minor version for the custom list?

Comment: this customer understand  how document major & minor version working on document libraries, so for the same purpose on libraries: he request the same on some lists.

Comment: for that, i think you need to wring some kind of Custom Event receiver, their is nothing available OOTB.

Answer (score 0):

The way minor version is set differs from DocLib's and lists.

Document libraries set the EnableMinorVersions to TRUE when minor versions are set, lists look at EnableModeration (which in the UI also locks up minor versions)

The following **boilerplate code** shows how to enforce cap on versions on existing lists

```
# iterate webs then lists as below
foreach ( $list in $lists )
{
    $title_ = $list.Title
    $baseType_ = $list.BaseType
    $isDocLib_ = ($baseType_ -eq [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseType]::DocumentLibrary)
    $enableMinorVersions_ = $list.EnableMinorVersions
    $majorVersionLimit_ = $list.MajorVersionLimit
    $minorVersionLimit_ = $list.MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit
    $enableModeration_ = $list.EnableModeration

    # set limit if no limit or limit larger than decided limit
    if ( $majorVersionLimit_ -gt $MajorVersionLimit -or $majorVersionLimit_ -eq 0 )
    {
        Write-Warning "`t`tEnforcing MajorVersionLimit"
        $list.MajorVersionLimit = $MajorVersionLimit
        $listIsDirty = $true
    }
    # set limit if minor is enabled and not set
    # NOTE: Only DocLibs use EnableMinorVersion lists use EnableModeration to allow minor versions
    if ( ($isDocLib_ -and $enableMinorVersions_ ) -and ( $minorVersionLimit_ -gt $MinorVersionLimit -or $minorVersionLimit_ -eq 0 ) -or
       ( -not $isDocLib_ -and $enableModeration_ ) -and ( $minorVersionLimit_ -gt $MinorVersionLimit -or $minorVersionLimit_ -eq 0 )
     )
    {
        Write-Warning "`t`tEnforcing MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit"
        $list.MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit = $MinorVersionLimit
        $listIsDirty = $true
    }

    $list.Update()

}
$web.Update()
```